# Accept Number only in editable column td html

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with validate number only in editable column for my table.
so here my html code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true' name="presentase"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this my js for number only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">>
 $(".allow_only_numbers").keydown(function (e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
              ((e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 86 || e.keyCode == 67) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
              (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                return;
            }
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
</script>
```

how to make the column can input number only on that "td" tag. where should i place the ".allow_only_numbers" in the column tag ?

so help me to solve this. thank you

Comment: can `<input type='number' />` help your cause? Its better and save your time

Comment: You talk about "editable column", yet in your HTML you wrote `contenteditable='false'`. Please correct or explain more.

Comment: i'm sorry i copy the false one, i also have the true one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put `allow_only_numbers` class to `td`

also your `contenteditable` needs to be `true`

```js
$(".allow_only_numbers").keydown(function (e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
              ((e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 86 || e.keyCode == 67) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
              (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                return;
            }
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100px" height="50px">
<tr>
<td class="allow_only_numbers" contenteditable='true' name="presentase"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even use formatter in table like the below code use a function to render the value in table

```
 <th data-field="DELETE_DOWNLOAD" data-align="center" data-formatter="deleteFileFormatter"></th>
```

where deleteFileFormatter is the function where value returned from the function will go to the table